# How can I stop a text link to go up each time it is selected?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm using Blogger.

I have modified a bit the CSS of the template, though I can't find why each time a link (section) is selected it goes up. At first I thought it was some *margin-top* issue, but I don't find a problem with it in the actual CSS.

Since I don't know how deep I can go to a CSS in Blogger, I don't know what else to do. I tried using the inspector in Chrome but there's nothing *wrong* or I'm blind.

Take a look: Select a link from the top and cry with me.

http://safetyinsolitude.blogspot.mx/

Comment: what browser/os? i don't see it in ff/win7

Comment: Sorry. Chrome, Win 8.1

Comment: add the relevant code here. that link will change eventually when you get it right and will help nobody who sees this question in the future.

Comment: For any folk out there in the same situation, now there's a solution. I can't add the code since there "isn't" a code, but, maybe, it was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following css-selector:

```
.tabs-inner .widget li {
      line-height: 3.2;
}
```

Comment: Perfect buddy. I knew it had something to do with line-weight, though I never thought to actually add it. Thanks, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
     .tabs-inner .widget span {
     line-height: 3.2;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: .6em 1em;
     border-left: 1px solid transparent;
     font: normal normal 14px Crimson Text;
     border-right: 0 solid #000000;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line height of the span.